# How to pass control to a HTML box and write a word in Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, keypress, selenium-ide

```
type   |  id=xxx   | abc
type   |  id=yyy   | def
```

After these two text boxes, I have to write a sentence in an HTML box, the HTML box has only a css value, but am not able to make focus on that box and write on it.
Can any one help me with this issue?

HTML of the box is,

```
<textarea id="html_field" class="Size3" name="html_field" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Could you share the HTML of the HTML box you are trying to type too?

Comment: I see you have added the html, now what do you want to do with this text area? I see that the display is none so it is not visible on the page.

Comment: @RemcoW I have a webpage, it consists of some text boxes, which I mentioned above and the HTML box. I have to enter text into to the HTML box so as to save the page. Since am not able to enter text, i am not able to save the page.

Comment: Have you tried using `sendKeys` command? Because that's what I use whenever I encounter a problem similar to yours.

Comment: @RodelBernal I have tried 'sendKeys' , but it is not working. Can you please post the example for 'sendKeys' command. I have to insert some text in the Text box after that I have to pass the control to the HTML box and do the operations there.

Comment: Now I see the problem. It's like RemcoW said, your display is set to none. You can't type in a text area that is not displayed in the first place.

Comment: @RodelBernal The HTML box is making use of "iframe". I don't really away of "iframe". Is there any particular way to do it?

Comment: You mean the text area is inside an iframe? If that's the case then you need to select first the iframe before interacting with its inside elements.

Comment: @RodelBernal yes..Can you please show can I do it. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113724/discussion-between-kripindas-and-rodel-bernal).